# POI: Ler a partir de linha especifica e enviar ao BD

Tags: java

Olá. Estou trabalhando num TCC em JAVA e uma de suas funções será leitura de arquivos EXCEL e o envio dos dados para o Banco de Dados.

Estou começando aos poucos no JAVA e algumas coisas ainda confundem bastante, e por isso tenho pesquisado bastante sobre isso. A questão é: Como faço para a partir do exemplo abaixo, eu consiga iniciar a leitura a partir da linha 5 do .xlsx e como devo exportar esses dados para o Banco de Dados?

Estou a 3 dias pesquisando e como não encontrei nada especifico, estou recorrendo ao StackOverflow... Obrigado desde já

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileInputStream fisPlanilha = null;

    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\wi-li\\Downloads\\PrograminhasLerXlsx\\xlsx\\planilhas\\planilhaDaAula.xlsx");
        fisPlanilha = new FileInputStream(file);

        //cria um workbook = planilha toda com todas as abas
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fisPlanilha);

        //recuperamos apenas a primeira aba ou primeira planilha
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //retorna todas as linhas da planilha 0 (aba 1)
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        //varre todas as linhas da planilha 0
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            //recebe cada linha da planilha
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            //pegamos todas as celulas desta linha
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();

            //varremos todas as celulas da linha atual
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                //criamos uma celula
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.println("TIPO STRING: " + cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.println("TIPO NUMERICO: " + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                        System.out.println("TIPO FORMULA: " + cell.getCellFormula());
                }

            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LendoXLSX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LendoXLSX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fisPlanilha.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LendoXLSX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Se você já consegue ler o arquivo .xlsx com esse código, para começar a leitura a partir da 5ª Linha é bem fácil, você pode simplesmente chamar `rowIterator.next()` (que avança uma linha na iteração) 5 vezes seguidas sem pegar o que é retornado. Para enviar para um BD, também não é difícil, mas vc precisará de um BD instalado e saber os comandos para criar tabelas e colunas, inserir dados nas células, etc... recomendo um tutorial iniciante de Java com BD.

Comment: Ótimo. Irei fuçar um pouco no código para implementar o `rowIterator.next()` e depois pesquiso mais sobre o BD. Obrigado.

Comment: sempre que você chama`rowIterator.next();` você avança na iteração, se você chamar essa instrução 4 vezes antes de entrar no loop, ao entrar no loop você irá capturar da 5ª linha em diante. Pesquise sobre "iterators", a interface "Iterable", ou mesmo o *padrão de projetos Iterator*.

Comment: Agora entendi melhor... era antes do loop ^^'
Quanto mais mexo nesse TCC, mas minha cabeça entra em parafuso kkk

Muito obrigado Douglas. Agora irei me aprofundar no banco de dados.